# How to get timely Alert Message in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, mailmessage, sql-job

In my Project I want to implement remainder on time basis that will send a message or remainder mail to my email ID and Mobile no.I am using 3 columns in sql server wiz complaint_date ,max_servedate ,status in which complaint_date is the date when user lock the Request ,max serve date is 1 day addition to compalint_date and status solved or not.now the main thing is that how to computer automatically send a mail or message.

Comment: You can either use SQl jobs if you want it from the database end or you can implement windows service if the work is to be done on application level. Its possible both ways. Try searching for these two.